# How to stop concurrent consumer consuming message in KAFKA?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple Kafka consumer micro-service application which consumes message from some topic and the same application is running in two different pool .

So when message is produced from producer and my app tries to consume the message from topic and it is consumed by one only in one pool.

How can I stop the concurrent message reading from consumer kafka. I want to consume the same message in both the pool.

What can be the possible solution for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

If your topic only has one partition, then only one consumer of the same `group.id` setting can read this partition. If you must have one partition for ordering purposes, then you need unique group ids for reading this data in multiple consumers.

Otherwise, if the topic has multiple partitions, then 2 consumers should actively be reading them.

You'd "stop" reading by not calling `poll()`.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer  and yes the thing is topic has multiple partitions, then 2 consumers  deployed on cloud reading concurrently. Can you please elaborate more on stop reading by not calling poll()

Comment: Okay, then I don't understand what you mean by "consumed by only one pool". A record will only go to one partition, therefore only one consumer is going to get that record. Regarding stopping, rather than do `while (true) { consumer.poll(); }`, you can not use a loop, or you can stop it by replacing the boolean condition. You could even call `consumer.close()`

Comment: @LearnThings consumer groups don't share data across consumer instances. This is only a feature of Kafka Streams API and meant for KTable access, not plain consumer streams

Comment: "consumed by only one pool" - So the app is has two instance deployed in cloud. So when producer publishes the message based on the partition now on consumer end there will be rebalancing of partition happen. But i don't want rebalancing here what i want is I want both my consumer consumes that record, no concurrency should happen

Comment: @LearnThings Producers don't cause rebalancing. It's not possible for more than one consumer in the same group to read the same event, ever.

Comment: I know Producers don't cause rebalancing it happens on consumer end via group coordinator based on group id redistribute the partition

Comment: I was just asking if its possible more than one consumer read the same event

Comment: It's possible if consumer1 fails to commit an offset before a rebalance to consumer2. However, using transactional producers and consumer read-isolation should help prevent this and yield exactly-once delivery